# One web + One GTM but different Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, multilingual

I have a web with different countries (languages) in different paths like

- domain.tld/en-en/
- domain.tld/za-en/
- domain.tld/de-de/
- ...

They all have the same page structure, so I would like to use the same GTM for all of them. But I would like to track those pages in different Google Analytic Accounts for better overview. Is this possible in GTM, or is there a way in Google Analytics to split everything by this path-structure?

Otherwise, my workaround would be to copy the GTM-Container X-Times, which would be not good for maintenance.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669207/implementing-two-analytics-propertys-in-one-container-with-gtm?rq=1, except that you need to use a regex table instead of a lookup table, with the page path as input variable.

Comment: Thank you, I think this https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-tag-manager-lookup-table-macro/#multi-account-or-multi-property-container should do the trick.

Comment: That's ancient, and lookup/regex tables are GTMs built-in replacement for that.